# Corrupt OST files for Gmail account in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap

I have some troubles with Gmail account in Office 2016 and 2019.
When I try to add the gmail account at Outlook start I see an error about the OST file corruption.
In AppData/Local/Microsoft/Office/outlook folder I have found many .ost.corrupt files.

I have tried to delete all ost files, remove the Outlook profile from "Mail" setting in control panel.
The Gmail account has IMAP activated, two factor autentication on and I made a password for app.

I have tried to reinstall Office, and moreover I have tried to update Office from 2016 to 2019 but it is still failing with the same messages.

[image]

Comment: It may be caused by a corrupted Outlook profile. Try to create another profile via *Control Panel > Mail > Show profiles*.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I have already tried it "...remove the Outlook profile from "Mail" setting in control panel.". :-(

Comment: You mean that this is happening in two different profiles?

Comment: I have tried to delete all profiles and create a new one, and it fails again. Is there any log about Outlook? I did not find anything in event-viewer

Comment: Weird. Is there something special about the Gmail account, such as huge messages or very many messages? Is there something special with the permissions of the folder where is the OST file?

Comment: The Gmail mailbox is 10GB, but I have limited the max messages per IMAP folder of 10000 in Gmail settings. The OST folder has full user permissions. The failre happens at the configuration of account, not during the messages download...

Comment: The question is to which folders is referring the message "The set of folders cannot be opened". Whether it refers to Gmail folders or local folders.

Comment: Have you tried SCANPST? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253 It will repair PST and OST files.

Comment: Yes I have tried scanpst, he found the problem but cannot recover. This is why I have deleted all profile/ost files and I have started from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

What's the version of your Outlook? (File > Office Account > About Outlook). Please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version.

And how did you add the Gmail account? Is your operation consistent with [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-gmail-account-to-outlook-70191667-9c52-4581-990e-e30318c2c081)?

Considering you have tried some troubleshooting, it's suggested that you could try to use the [Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-the-microsoft-support-and-recovery-assistant-e90bb691-c2a7-4697-a94f-88836856c72f) to check if there're any problems.

If it doesn't work, please continue with the following troubleshooting:

- Considering the impact of some add ins, It is suggested that you
  could try to start outlook in safe mode(win+R>type: outlook /safe) to
  check whether it works normally.
- Check if the reading pane is damaged: Close Outlook>Choose Start >
  Run, In the Open box, type Outlook.exe /resetnavpane, and then choose
  OK

Comment: Hi thenks for the tip, I have followed the procedure to add Gmail account, but it doesnt work. I tried with /safe and it doesn't work. I don't think it can be a plugin, consider I have re-installed office more than one time

Comment: You mean you have successfully configured the Gmial account, but failed to start outlook, right? If so, have you tried all the above troubleshoting methods, which can narrow the scope of the problem.

Comment: Yes the account was configured, but the error appears at outlook startup. At the end I have reinstalled windows... and now it works. I solved the issue, but this is not a good solution.

Comment: Anyway, glad to hear that your problem has been solved.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would you like to write this solution as answer and mark it as the answer? In this way, other people with similar problems can get reference.

Comment: I think reinstalling windows is not a solution :-) It works

Comment: Well, have a nice day!